# Understanding concurrency better (with locks)

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, operating-system

I'm trying to understand concurrency and using locks better, but this dummy example I made is throwing me off:

```
int i = 0;

void foo() {
    int n = i;
    i = i + 1;
    printf("foo: %d\n", n);
}

void boo() {
    int n = i;
    i = i + 1;
    printf("boo: %d\n", n);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    pthread_t p1, p2;

    pthread_create(&p1, NULL, (void*) foo, NULL);
    pthread_create(&p2, NULL, (void*) boo, NULL);

    // wait for threads to finish
    pthread_join(p1, NULL);
    pthread_join(p2, NULL);

    // final print
    printf("main: %d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

If I understand correctly, the `i = i + 1;` in both `foo()` and `bar()` can cause some unexpected behaviour. One unexpected behaviour is that we'll get both "foo: 0" and "bar: 0" since it's possible that a context switch happened right before the `i = i + 1;` and so `n` is always 0. I think the expected behaviour is that "foo: 0" "bar: 1" or "bar: 0" "foo: 1" (please correct me if I'm wrong).

To fix this, I added locks:

```
int i = 0;
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void foo() {
    int n = i;
    i = i + 1;
    printf("foo: %d\n", n);
}

void boo() {
    int n = i;
    i = i + 1;
    printf("boo: %d\n", n);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    pthread_t p1, p2;

    printf("Locking foo\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("Locked foo\n");
    pthread_create(&p1, NULL, (void*) foo, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    printf("Unlocked foo\n");

    printf("Locking boo\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("Locked boo\n");
    pthread_create(&p2, NULL, (void*) boo, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    printf("Unlocked boo\n");

    // wait for threads to finish
    pthread_join(p1, NULL);
    pthread_join(p2, NULL);

    // final print
    printf("main: %d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

I think this would fix the unexpected results, but I got a surprising output when I ran this:

```
Locking foo
Locked foo
Unlocked foo
Locking boo
Locked boo
foo: 0
Unlocked boo
boo: 1
main: 2
```

It looks like the program locked the first thread that calls foo() and then immediately unlocked it without actually executing the printf? It then goes on to locking the thread that calls boo() and does weird things out of order. Can someone explain this behaviour? I would of thought the output would have looked like:

```
Locking foo
Locked foo
foo: 0
Unlocked foo
Locking boo
Locked boo
boo: 1
Unlocked boo
main: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locking should take place in the functions like here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int i = 0;
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void foo() {
    printf("Locking foo\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("Locked foo\n");
    int n = i;
    i = i + 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    printf("Unlocked foo\n");
    printf("foo: %d\n", n);
}

void boo() {
    printf("Locking boo\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("Locked boo\n");
    int n = i;
    i = i + 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    printf("Unlocked boo\n");
    printf("boo: %d\n", n);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    pthread_t p1, p2;
    pthread_create(&p1, NULL, (void*) foo, NULL);
    pthread_create(&p2, NULL, (void*) boo, NULL);

    // wait for threads to finish
    pthread_join(p1, NULL);
    pthread_join(p2, NULL);

    // final print
    printf("main: %d\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

This way, when one function locks, the other function will be blocked until the lock is unlocked.

Comment: I tried your code, and I got this output: 
```Locking foo
Locked foo
Locking boo
Locked boo
Unlocked boo
boo: 1
Unlocked foo
foo: 0
main: 2```
it looks lilke foo was locked and then followed by boo getting locked. This shouldn't happen right since foo was already locked and boo should have been blocked?

Comment: @FrankLee That might just have to do with the way `printf` is working when its called from multiple threads. I'll check it out though.

Comment: @FrankLee I just tested the code and I got the correct output
`Locking foo Locked foo
Unlocked foo
foo: 0
Locking boo
Locked boo
Unlocked boo
boo: 1
main: 2` The print statements are not controlled by the lock so the order is not guaranteed.

Comment: I see, thank you. With this, then our only possibilities are foo: 0, boo: 1 OR boo: 0, foo: 1. This is because the a lock in boo will prevent foo from executing and vice versa?

Comment: @FrankLee Yes exactly. Your possibilities are correct though they will  not necessarily show up in the 0 then 1 order as those print statements are not in the lock.

Answer (score 2):

Your choice of wording betrays a likely serious misunderstanding:

> It looks like the program locked the first thread that calls foo()

Programs do not lock threads.  Rather, *threads acquire locks* (or, equivalently, threads lock mutexes).  That can include a program's main thread, too.  Mutual exclusion is achieved among cooperating (!) threads by the fact that only one thread can hold any particular lock (mutex) at a time.

Thus, if thread B has a given mutex locked when thread A attempts to acquire it then thread A's acquisition attempt will block (the return of the `pthread_mutex_lock()` call will be delayed).  Thread A will not proceed until it does acquire the mutex.  Thus, the boundaries of critical regions are defined by calls to `pthread_mutex_lock()` and `pthread_mutex_unlock()` on the same mutex.  Approximately speaking, every participating thread must acquire the appropriate mutex before accessing shared shared variables, and each one must release the mutex when it is done to allow other threads to acquire it in turn.

Other answers have already presented details of how that might look in your example program.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the locks incorrectly. You lock the mutex, start the thread, and unlock it. The thread runs without any knowledge of the locking operations. Use the lock in the functions sharing memory:

```
void foo() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    int n = i;
    i = i + 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    printf("foo: %d\n", n);
}
```

Do the same with `boo` function.

Comment: I thought locks only worked per thread? Wouldn't this mean foo and bar would have still have no knowledge of the locks?

Comment: @FrankLee, `foo` and `bar` have to know locks. Each thread locks the same lock entering into their critical section.

Comment: Thanks. The answer below gave the same suggestion and I tried it out. It looks like sometimes foo is getting locked but then boo is then also getting immediately locked. Can you help me explain this?

Comment: You're probably seeing the println for locking of `boo` before the println for unlocking of `foo`. If you move printlns into lock, you'll see the correct order.